# java program to find m%n without using % operator and without using for loop

Tags: java, operators, modulo

java program to find m%n without using % operator, i got only using %, can some one help me without % operator?

```
public class mod{
public static void main(String[] args){
int m=3, n=2; 
System.out.print("m%n is"+m%n); 
}}
```

I want to find m%n without % operator

Comment: sum n m-times, while sum<m, return m-sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.out.print("m%n is"+(m-m/n*n));
```

Comment: @OP why do you accept the only answer that does not compile? The `-` operator is not defined on strings, so the expression should be in brackets.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need double. You can just do

```
int mod = m - m / n * n;
```

Remainder is calculated as a result of a division and many cpus have an integer divide and remainder in a single operations.  For this reason, it is a good idea to put them together so the JIT can optimise them. e.g. the following code could be a single machine code instruction

```
int a = m / n;
int b = m % n;
```

This combination is very common for turning integers into text as `/ 10` and `% 10` are used in combination.

Answer (score 3):

It's as easy as

```
m - n * (m / n);
```

Answer (score 2):

`n * ((double)m / n - m / n)` is one way.

This works since `m / n` will be performed in integer arithmetic, but `(double)m / n` in floating point due to the promotion of one of the integers.

Answer (score 1):

There are hundreds of ways to do this, as well as the division/multiplication approach you can also do things like this for example:

```
while (m>=n)
    m-=n;
```

It gets harder if all loops are banned not just for loops but there are still options such as recursion etc.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can:

```
m - (m / n) * n;
```